# Lower bounds for $|\sin 1| + |\sin 2| + \cdots + |\sin (3n)|$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, summation

> **Problem**: Find Lower bounds for $|\sin 1| + |\sin 2| + \cdots + |\sin (3n)|$.

This is the follow up of [Prove that $|\sin 1| + |\sin 2| + |\sin 3| +\cdots+ |\sin 3n| > 8n/5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920411/prove-that-sin-1-sin-2-sin-3-cdots-sin-3n-8n-5).

**My attempt**

By the identity
$$\left|\sin x\right| = \frac{2}{\pi}-\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)}\cos(2k x),$$
we have
\begin{align}
&|\sin 1| + |\sin 2| + \cdots + |\sin (3n)|\\
=\ & \frac{6n}{\pi} - \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)}\Big(\cos(2k) + \cos (4k) + \cdots + \cos (6kn)\Big)\\
=\ & \frac{6n}{\pi} - \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)} \frac{\cos ((3n+1)k) \sin (3nk)}{\sin k}.
\end{align}
We need to find upper bounds for $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)} \frac{\cos ((3n+1)k) \sin (3nk)}{\sin k}$.
A such upper bound is give by
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)} \frac{\cos ((3n+1)k) \sin (3nk)}{\sin k}\\
\le \ & \sum_{k = 1}^{5000} \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)} \frac{1}{|\sin k|}
+ \sum_{k = 5001}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)} \cdot 3n\\
\le \ & \frac{23}{19} + \frac{6n}{10001\pi}
\end{align}
where we have used $|\frac{\sin (3nk)}{\sin k}| \le 3n$. Thus, we have
$$|\sin 1| + |\sin 2| + \cdots + |\sin (3n)| \ge \frac{6n}{\pi} - \frac{23}{19} - \frac{6n}{10001\pi}.$$

However, this upper bound is not satisfactory to me. I hope to get better upper bounds.
Some numerical experiment make me even guess $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi(4k^2-1)} \frac{\cos ((3n+1)k) \sin (3nk)}{\sin k} \le C$ for some absolute constant $C$.

Any comments and solutions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: This is related to question of mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624591/an-inequality-for-a-trigonometric-sum

Comment: It seems that $$\frac{\sum _{k=1}^{3 n} \left| \sin k\right| }{n}\to \beta\text{ as }n\to\infty$$ where $\beta\approx 1.90986$.

Comment: @Raffaele  Could it be $\beta = \frac{6}{\pi}$?

Comment: @OmranKouba Yes, thank you.

Comment: In my question, the OP who posted the answer mentioned the lower bound can be proven using the Equidistribution Theorem.

Comment: @RichardKiddman Thank you. According to the last sentence in his answer, "but I am now confident that the limit above really does exist and that it is equal to $\frac{6}{\pi}$", he just pointed out the direction. I hope he can give a rigorous and detailed answer here.

Comment: @RichardKiddman Also, even when the limit is proved, we need to find bounds such as $\sum _{k=1}^{3 n} \left| \sin k\right| \ge \frac{6n}{\pi} - 1$ which may be far from just finding the limit.